# How to Disable Auto Executing Script in A Particular Page Only

Tags: plugins, pages

I used this https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-wp/ plugin to add an opt-in form on every page. Now I want to disable a page to auto-insert this form and make a landing page. I'll use a different opt-in form for that landing page, how can I do that? Thanks

Note: that plugin does not support except page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin which is helping me to solve this issue. The plugin link is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-load-filter/

Answer (score 0):

You either need a widget control plugin, like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ah-display-widgets/), [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-options/) or activate the widget visibility module of [Jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/). Or make whole sidebars content aware, like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-aware-sidebars/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not talking about the sidebar, the plugin auto inserts an opt-in form bottom of the content area. How can I stop that for a single page? Thanks

Comment: It seems the premium version of the plugin has a filter "Never show on these pages". So this id deliberately left out to make you pay fro the Premium.